# Is it possible for a customer to download a file after paying for the order?

Tags: product, checkout, customer, downloadable, file-upload

I sell electrical products and I want customers to download or receive an email with the instruction manual for the product.

I don't want that the manual viewable on the website before the customer pays for the order.

What steps do I need to perform to achieve this?

Comment: Look up Downloadable Products.

Comment: It's not exactly that I want, because I don't want the product is displayed on the Front end.

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding how the Downloadable product works. The customer won't be able to get to the product until the order status is set to the status defined in Admin -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Downloadable Product Options in `Order Item Status to Enable Downloads`.  Until that Order Status is met then the user will not be able to get to the downloadable item.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a bundle with two fixed options, the real product and the manual as downloadable product. Make the downloadable product not visible individually and set the price to zero.

After purchasing and paying the bundle, the customer will be able to download the attached files from his account menu.

You don't want to make the real product itself downloadable because then Magento will assume that no shipment is needed.